# 'The type FileConfigurationSource does not contain the ConfigurationElementTypeAttribute.'

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have the following XML in a config file I am trying to reference:

```
  <enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="">
    <sources>
      <add name="AMPS SAV Application" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" filePath="C:\Trusted\Source Code\AMPS\Planning\SAV\Mainline-xdev\Apps\SavFvwEditor\bin\Debug\app.config" />
    </sources>
  </enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
```

I receive the error:

> "System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'The type FileConfigurationSource does not contain the ConfigurationElementTypeAttribute.'"

when I attempt to read from this file.

I am not quite sure what that means. Does it mean that my code lacks a ConfigurationElementTypeAttribute, and needs one? Or does it mean that it has a ConfigurationElementTypeAttribute, and should not? Is there any obvious way to fix this issue?

Comment: I seem to recall (from using that library before) something like the type attribute needing to come before any other attribute. You might try that.

Comment: Sounds like you hit a type conflict, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8910bbc-5110-4cfc-b59d-8ac3a60fa992/esb-21-not-working-with-other-application-block-versions?forum=biztalkesb